# Remove excessive occurrences

Tags: code-golf, number, array

Given an array \$A\$ of positive integers between \$1\$ and \$9\$ inclusive and a positive integer \$n\$, remove all integers in \$A\$ which appear more than \$n\$ times.

For example:

```
             [1,2,3,2,3,2,4,1,2], n = 2
Occurrence:   1 1 1 2 2 3 1 2 4
Keep?         1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
Kept values: [1,2,3,2,3,  4,1  ]
```

so the output is `[1,2,3,2,3,4,1]`

You can assume that:

- At least one element will always appear more than \$n\$ times
- At least one element will appear fewer than \$n\$ times
- \$A\$ will have a minimum of 2 distinct elements
- \$n\$ and the length of \$A\$ are within the integer bounds of your language.

You may take input and output in [any convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). As the elements of \$A\$ are digits, you may also take input as an integer, or a single string, if that suits you.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Test cases

```
A, n -> out
[7,3,3,9], 1 -> [7,3,9]
[4,1,7,7,4,2,1], 1 -> [4,1,7,2]
[6,9,7,6,7,9,9], 2 -> [6,9,7,6,7,9]
[6,5,3,9,4,9,6,9], 2 -> [6,5,3,9,4,9,6]
[4,8,9,7,3,1,7,5,4,6], 1 -> [4,8,9,7,3,1,5,6]
[5,6,7,8,1,7,3,3,6,4], 1 -> [5,6,7,8,1,3,4]
[2,3,8,1,6,4,8,2,8,3], 2 -> [2,3,8,1,6,4,8,2,3]
[4,1,4,4,2,4,4,5,7,1,3], 1 -> [4,1,2,5,7,3]
[1,5,5,2,5,1,4,1,6,7,7,6,9,8,8,1,7,8,1,3,1,1,7,4], 3 -> [1,5,5,2,5,1,4,1,6,7,7,6,9,8,8,7,8,3,4]
[8,8,6,2,9,6,4,7,1,2,9,5,5,6,6,2,5,8,9,1,2,8,4,4,7,2,1,1], 3 -> [8,8,6,2,9,6,4,7,1,2,9,5,5,6,2,5,8,9,1,4,4,7,1]
[8,8,4,9,7,1,2,9,8,8,5,2,2,9,1,7,4,6,6,8,6,6,1,6,1,9,2,8,5,1,2,6,1,7,6,4,7,9], 4 -> [8,8,4,9,7,1,2,9,8,8,5,2,2,9,1,7,4,6,6,6,6,1,1,9,2,5,7,4,7]
[8,8,9,2,7,4,7,5,6,9,7,2,7,7,6,2,6,9,6,3,5,1,1,6,2,8,7,4,2,4,5,9,3,3,3,3,7,4,8,7,5,4,1,4,7,8], 2 -> [8,8,9,2,7,4,7,5,6,9,2,6,3,5,1,1,4,3]
[6,8,1,8,6,9,2,2,5,8,7,6,2,5,4,3,3,1,4,2,7,1,6,3,9,8,9,5,2,6,8,8,7,7,5,2,5,1,4,7,5,5,3,7,6,3,7,6,3,6,7], 4 -> [6,8,1,8,6,9,2,2,5,8,7,6,2,5,4,3,3,1,4,2,7,1,6,3,9,8,9,5,7,7,5,1,4,3]
[1,3,5,6,1,2,8,8,8,4,4,4,5,8,9,9,6,4,5,3,8,7,9,7,8,6,1,6,1,6,4,5,5,3,9,3,5,4,2,1,6,6,5,4,2,6,2,1,1,1,5,5], 2 -> [1,3,5,6,1,2,8,8,4,4,5,9,9,6,3,7,7,2]
[9,9,9,4,6,1,5,4,5,3,7,9,8,9,8,2,9,1,3,4,9,5,8,7,8,6,1,9,9,5,1,3,1,9,5,7,3,5,9,6,6,2,2,4,1,4,2,1,7,5,3,7,9,8,2,3,1,6], 9 -> [9,9,9,4,6,1,5,4,5,3,7,9,8,9,8,2,9,1,3,4,9,5,8,7,8,6,1,9,9,5,1,3,1,5,7,3,5,6,6,2,2,4,1,4,2,1,7,5,3,7,8,2,3,1,6]
[9,6,3,5,5,2,8,2,9,6,7,9,5,3,1,1,1,3,6,9,4,3,6,9,2,2,3,7,5,3,9,5,2,1,1,1,1,6,2,2,4,6,1,5,7,3,7,9,5,3,1,2,6,4,3,1,7,9,3,8,5,2,4,2,8,2,6,7,3,9,1,7,9,4,7,4], 5 -> [9,6,3,5,5,2,8,2,9,6,7,9,5,3,1,1,1,3,6,9,4,3,6,9,2,2,3,7,5,5,2,1,1,6,4,7,7,4,7,8,4,8,4]
[7,1,8,2,2,1,4,9,8,6,5,1,9,7,5,5,8,1,7,8,6,8,5,9,3,2,7,9,4,3,9,1,5,2,5,7,8,5,2,6,6,2,7,6,2,9,3,3,5,3,7,9,8,7,3,6,7,4,6,1,4,5,8,9,8,6,9,1,1,1,8,2,4,2,9,3,4,2,9,6], 8 -> [7,1,8,2,2,1,4,9,8,6,5,1,9,7,5,5,8,1,7,8,6,8,5,9,3,2,7,9,4,3,9,1,5,2,5,7,8,5,2,6,6,2,7,6,2,9,3,3,5,3,7,9,8,7,3,6,4,6,1,4,8,9,6,1,1,2,4,3,4]
[7,2,8,9,7,5,1,4,6,8,6,9,1,8,6,2,2,6,1,1,6,8,4,5,2,6,5,5,4,5,5,3,6,8,3,7,9,3,9,8,4,9,6,7,2,7,9,2,4,8,3,3,2,5,9,1,4,6,4,8,2,5,8,6,8,1,8,3,3,9,4,8,1,1,2,9,1,9,3,3,7], 11 -> [7,2,8,9,7,5,1,4,6,8,6,9,1,8,6,2,2,6,1,1,6,8,4,5,2,6,5,5,4,5,5,3,6,8,3,7,9,3,9,8,4,9,6,7,2,7,9,2,4,8,3,3,2,5,9,1,4,6,4,8,2,5,8,6,8,1,8,3,3,9,4,1,1,2,9,1,9,3,3,7]
[7,7,6,5,9,7,2,6,1,4,4,5,4,3,1,7,5,5,8,1,6,3,9,3,3,9,5,9,1,2,4,3,8,2,6,6,5,2,8,7,5,6,5,7,3,2,5,3,5,8,6,1,9,7,4,3,9,8,2,4,5,7,8,8,2,8,1,8,7,8,7,6,3,8,6,7,9,4,6,1,6,1,2,5,6,7,7,2,8,3,2,1,7], 11 -> [7,7,6,5,9,7,2,6,1,4,4,5,4,3,1,7,5,5,8,1,6,3,9,3,3,9,5,9,1,2,4,3,8,2,6,6,5,2,8,7,5,6,5,7,3,2,5,3,5,8,6,1,9,7,4,3,9,8,2,4,5,7,8,8,2,8,1,8,7,8,7,6,3,8,6,7,9,4,6,1,6,1,2,2,3,2,1]
[3,4,1,1,2,4,4,8,4,9,1,1,7,7,6,8,6,2,9,4,2,9,9,7,5,7,6,5,3,7,6,6,1,9,1,5,2,4,9,6,1,5,4,1,7,2,4,3,8,5,1,9,5,9,1,7,4,7,3,1,2,1,3,8,7,9,2,5,1,6,2,4,5,9,1,5,5,5,2,6,3,7,2,2,5,7,6,8,3,7,5,9,3,3,9], 7 -> [3,4,1,1,2,4,4,8,4,9,1,1,7,7,6,8,6,2,9,4,2,9,9,7,5,7,6,5,3,7,6,6,1,9,1,5,2,4,9,6,1,5,4,7,2,3,8,5,9,5,7,3,2,3,8,2,5,6,3,8,3]
```

[Test case generator](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98ySKHC0lLh4a4uhYc7Fisc2hxxaAnX4R2H2w@3Bx6beGi/go7Cke5HG9cFqjzc2fCoYWbEsU0qQJGHO1epHFtic2hpyMPd3Y8ad5zq1ld4uHOtisKhrQp6QKGHO2cpZD1qWvOoYa6OwuEZ0VlAIxTCgQIKWQpGQHmVcBWFo3sUHjXM0QERCrp2QGqugtv///8NDQA). Run with no arguments to have a max length of 100 for \$A\$. For a different max length (no larger than \$891\$), run with that as an argument.

Comment: Brownie points for beating my 8 byte Jelly answer

Comment: Can the n be passed before A?

Comment: @manatwork Yeah, you can take input in either order

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/86503/95792)

Comment: I like how well thought and friendly this challenge is: no corner cases with empty arrays; values are single-digit positive integers so more esolangs can participate

Comment: @LuisMendo I like "Remove excessive repetitions", changed to that :)

Comment: Correction: brownie points for beating 6 bytes in Jelly

Answer (score 16):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) -vn=, 9

```
a[$1]++<n
```

This is so competitive with the golfing-language answers, I feel like I might have misunderstood the question - did I?

The limit n is passed as a variable at the command line with `-vn=<value>`. The array is read from STDIN.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/MVrFMFZb2ybv/39DLlMgNAJiQy4TIDbjMgdCMy5LLgsgNASyQaQxEIPYJv91y/JsjQE)

Comment: I love this.  I'm not familiar with the rules around command line args, so just asking out of curiosity, but should the `-vn=` count as part of the byte count?  Eg, in JS or ruby, you have to pay for your named function arguments.

Comment: @Jonah I agree with you, and it used to be like that in the past. But there's a meta [rule](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/36398) that they should not be counted :-/

Comment: @LuisMendo I don't think that policy would apply in this case, because the `-vn=` is not modifying the behaviour of the language, but is part of the calling syntax

Comment: Perhaps the answer should specify “AWK `-vn=`” as the language name (though that isn't perfect either).

Comment: @Lynn Yes, I think that's a convenient way to deal with this - edited - thanks.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 35 bytes

Expects `(A)(n)`, where `A` is an array of digit characters.

```javascript
a=>n=>a.filter(v=>!(a[~v]+=v)[n+9])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdHNjoIwFAXg/TyFw6qNHQ39o12UFyFdNA5MNAQmalj66nhb2kmjMCY3CoTPc3ovbnK30/X8e/8axu927szsTD2Y2h26c39vr2gy9SdyzWOyezPhZthri@fTONzGvj304w/qUFNUBSlYHF1YjEqMd/99jsddUxFGtP14tTgYJUwVx1/TcG/D9RYnJakIfddkSLRIMn7rlJJuaJJo0CSMXhfFX9cln476qrqIwrclHEaud1ZZUpadgYj/IfP@S2cVcjLoLtZUkXVWmZg2JYP8oorQW4HJCH83aXw3eTKmU3FLKjzPTsGbFCwvSuIzw9X21nm28fRbxNxlsn3etHUK3eEM7PwE)

#### How?

We use the underlying object of `a[]` to keep track of the number of times each digit has appeared in the string.

By using `~v`, we make sure that we use a *property* of the object (a negative value as a string) rather than an *index* of the array (which is already filled with the input values).

The first time we append `v` to `a[~v]`, we get *undefined* coerced to a string followed by the digit character. Because `"undefined"` is 9 characters long, we know that we've reached `n+1` occurrences of `v` by testing `a[~v][n+9]`.

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes

Expects `(A)(n)`, where `A` is an array of integers.

```javascript
a=>n=>a.filter(v=>(a[~v]=-~a[~v])<=n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDRCoMgFIbv9xRdKtgizUqYvUh0IVuNRthoo8tevR1PrJYrMeF8fp6f8zCjeV2H9vkObX@r50bPRhdWF@bctN27HsioC2LKaax0OOFJL9rS@drbV9/V566/k4aUGROwVEVJTGmw/6IoQK6qk2clLGYZrIRxFnuusxbO/7yUKainsBX25J73ww9c6bJATwU39vbi/vCDxDm@LTCZhFvpmntJvHF54EtMlaPtJpayZOdvXADxbQ5Vx8CCk8MWa35n@1wcTjzBebu/hF4xvuESfCfOsS6q@QM)

Answer (score 9):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
n¹*u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P@/QTq3S////RxvpGOtY6BjqmOmYAGkjIDaO/W8EAA)

I've tried a few different ways, but [Razetime's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219645/62393) turned out to be very concise in Husk.

#### Explanation

```
n¹*u    Function of two arguments: A=[6,9,7,6,7,9,9], n=2
   u    Unique values of A: [6,9,7]
  *     Repeated n times: [6,9,7,6,9,7]
n¹      Intersected with A: [6,9,7,6,7,9]
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <sup><s>6</s></sup> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
°º☻¿_
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=f8a702a85f&i=1+,+%5B7,3,3,9%5D%0A1+,+%5B4,1,7,7,4,2,1%5D%0A2+,+%5B6,9,7,6,7,9,9%5D%0A2+,+%5B6,5,3,9,4,9,6,9%5D%0A1+,+%5B4,8,9,7,3,1,7,5,4,6%5D%0A1+,+%5B5,6,7,8,1,7,3,3,6,4%5D%0A2+,+%5B2,3,8,1,6,4,8,2,8,3%5D%0A1+,+%5B4,1,4,4,2,4,4,5,7,1,3%5D%0A3+,+%5B1,5,5,2,5,1,4,1,6,7,7,6,9,8,8,1,7,8,1,3,1,1,7,4%5D%0A3+,+%5B8,8,6,2,9,6,4,7,1,2,9,5,5,6,6,2,5,8,9,1,2,8,4,4,7,2,1,1%5D%0A4+,+%5B8,8,4,9,7,1,2,9,8,8,5,2,2,9,1,7,4,6,6,8,6,6,1,6,1,9,2,8,5,1,2,6,1,7,6,4,7,9%5D%0A2+,+%5B8,8,9,2,7,4,7,5,6,9,7,2,7,7,6,2,6,9,6,3,5,1,1,6,2,8,7,4,2,4,5,9,3,3,3,3,7,4,8,7,5,4,1,4,7,8%5D%0A4+,+%5B6,8,1,8,6,9,2,2,5,8,7,6,2,5,4,3,3,1,4,2,7,1,6,3,9,8,9,5,2,6,8,8,7,7,5,2,5,1,4,7,5,5,3,7,6,3,7,6,3,6,7%5D%0A2+,+%5B1,3,5,6,1,2,8,8,8,4,4,4,5,8,9,9,6,4,5,3,8,7,9,7,8,6,1,6,1,6,4,5,5,3,9,3,5,4,2,1,6,6,5,4,2,6,2,1,1,1,5,5%5D%0A9+,+%5B9,9,9,4,6,1,5,4,5,3,7,9,8,9,8,2,9,1,3,4,9,5,8,7,8,6,1,9,9,5,1,3,1,9,5,7,3,5,9,6,6,2,2,4,1,4,2,1,7,5,3,7,9,8,2,3,1,6%5D%0A5+,+%5B9,6,3,5,5,2,8,2,9,6,7,9,5,3,1,1,1,3,6,9,4,3,6,9,2,2,3,7,5,3,9,5,2,1,1,1,1,6,2,2,4,6,1,5,7,3,7,9,5,3,1,2,6,4,3,1,7,9,3,8,5,2,4,2,8,2,6,7,3,9,1,7,9,4,7,4%5D%0A8+,+%5B7,1,8,2,2,1,4,9,8,6,5,1,9,7,5,5,8,1,7,8,6,8,5,9,3,2,7,9,4,3,9,1,5,2,5,7,8,5,2,6,6,2,7,6,2,9,3,3,5,3,7,9,8,7,3,6,7,4,6,1,4,5,8,9,8,6,9,1,1,1,8,2,4,2,9,3,4,2,9,6%5D%0A11+,+%5B7,2,8,9,7,5,1,4,6,8,6,9,1,8,6,2,2,6,1,1,6,8,4,5,2,6,5,5,4,5,5,3,6,8,3,7,9,3,9,8,4,9,6,7,2,7,9,2,4,8,3,3,2,5,9,1,4,6,4,8,2,5,8,6,8,1,8,3,3,9,4,8,1,1,2,9,1,9,3,3,7%5D%0A11+,+%5B7,7,6,5,9,7,2,6,1,4,4,5,4,3,1,7,5,5,8,1,6,3,9,3,3,9,5,9,1,2,4,3,8,2,6,6,5,2,8,7,5,6,5,7,3,2,5,3,5,8,6,1,9,7,4,3,9,8,2,4,5,7,8,8,2,8,1,8,7,8,7,6,3,8,6,7,9,4,6,1,6,1,2,5,6,7,7,2,8,3,2,1,7%5D%0A7+,+%5B3,4,1,1,2,4,4,8,4,9,1,1,7,7,6,8,6,2,9,4,2,9,9,7,5,7,6,5,3,7,6,6,1,9,1,5,2,4,9,6,1,5,4,1,7,2,4,3,8,5,1,9,5,9,1,7,4,7,3,1,2,1,3,8,7,9,2,5,1,6,2,4,5,9,1,5,5,5,2,6,3,7,2,2,5,7,6,8,3,7,5,9,3,3,9%5D%0A&m=2)

Output as a string of codepoints(since stax prints all numeric arrays as strings). [Verifiable version](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=cua*%7CbJ&i=1+,+%5B7,3,3,9%5D%0A1+,+%5B4,1,7,7,4,2,1%5D%0A2+,+%5B6,9,7,6,7,9,9%5D%0A2+,+%5B6,5,3,9,4,9,6,9%5D%0A1+,+%5B4,8,9,7,3,1,7,5,4,6%5D%0A1+,+%5B5,6,7,8,1,7,3,3,6,4%5D%0A2+,+%5B2,3,8,1,6,4,8,2,8,3%5D%0A1+,+%5B4,1,4,4,2,4,4,5,7,1,3%5D%0A3+,+%5B1,5,5,2,5,1,4,1,6,7,7,6,9,8,8,1,7,8,1,3,1,1,7,4%5D%0A3+,+%5B8,8,6,2,9,6,4,7,1,2,9,5,5,6,6,2,5,8,9,1,2,8,4,4,7,2,1,1%5D%0A4+,+%5B8,8,4,9,7,1,2,9,8,8,5,2,2,9,1,7,4,6,6,8,6,6,1,6,1,9,2,8,5,1,2,6,1,7,6,4,7,9%5D%0A2+,+%5B8,8,9,2,7,4,7,5,6,9,7,2,7,7,6,2,6,9,6,3,5,1,1,6,2,8,7,4,2,4,5,9,3,3,3,3,7,4,8,7,5,4,1,4,7,8%5D%0A4+,+%5B6,8,1,8,6,9,2,2,5,8,7,6,2,5,4,3,3,1,4,2,7,1,6,3,9,8,9,5,2,6,8,8,7,7,5,2,5,1,4,7,5,5,3,7,6,3,7,6,3,6,7%5D%0A2+,+%5B1,3,5,6,1,2,8,8,8,4,4,4,5,8,9,9,6,4,5,3,8,7,9,7,8,6,1,6,1,6,4,5,5,3,9,3,5,4,2,1,6,6,5,4,2,6,2,1,1,1,5,5%5D%0A9+,+%5B9,9,9,4,6,1,5,4,5,3,7,9,8,9,8,2,9,1,3,4,9,5,8,7,8,6,1,9,9,5,1,3,1,9,5,7,3,5,9,6,6,2,2,4,1,4,2,1,7,5,3,7,9,8,2,3,1,6%5D%0A5+,+%5B9,6,3,5,5,2,8,2,9,6,7,9,5,3,1,1,1,3,6,9,4,3,6,9,2,2,3,7,5,3,9,5,2,1,1,1,1,6,2,2,4,6,1,5,7,3,7,9,5,3,1,2,6,4,3,1,7,9,3,8,5,2,4,2,8,2,6,7,3,9,1,7,9,4,7,4%5D%0A8+,+%5B7,1,8,2,2,1,4,9,8,6,5,1,9,7,5,5,8,1,7,8,6,8,5,9,3,2,7,9,4,3,9,1,5,2,5,7,8,5,2,6,6,2,7,6,2,9,3,3,5,3,7,9,8,7,3,6,7,4,6,1,4,5,8,9,8,6,9,1,1,1,8,2,4,2,9,3,4,2,9,6%5D%0A11+,+%5B7,2,8,9,7,5,1,4,6,8,6,9,1,8,6,2,2,6,1,1,6,8,4,5,2,6,5,5,4,5,5,3,6,8,3,7,9,3,9,8,4,9,6,7,2,7,9,2,4,8,3,3,2,5,9,1,4,6,4,8,2,5,8,6,8,1,8,3,3,9,4,8,1,1,2,9,1,9,3,3,7%5D%0A11+,+%5B7,7,6,5,9,7,2,6,1,4,4,5,4,3,1,7,5,5,8,1,6,3,9,3,3,9,5,9,1,2,4,3,8,2,6,6,5,2,8,7,5,6,5,7,3,2,5,3,5,8,6,1,9,7,4,3,9,8,2,4,5,7,8,8,2,8,1,8,7,8,7,6,3,8,6,7,9,4,6,1,6,1,2,5,6,7,7,2,8,3,2,1,7%5D%0A7+,+%5B3,4,1,1,2,4,4,8,4,9,1,1,7,7,6,8,6,2,9,4,2,9,9,7,5,7,6,5,3,7,6,6,1,9,1,5,2,4,9,6,1,5,4,1,7,2,4,3,8,5,1,9,5,9,1,7,4,7,3,1,2,1,3,8,7,9,2,5,1,6,2,4,5,9,1,5,5,5,2,6,3,7,2,2,5,7,6,8,3,7,5,9,3,3,9%5D%0A&m=2)

### Explanation

```
cua*|b
c       copy the list
 u      uniquify
  a     bring the count to the top
   *    repeat the elements n times
    |b  multiset intersect
```

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
t&=Rsi>~)
```

Inputs `A`,  then `n`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v0TNNqg4065O8///aEMFIwVjKDZRAPJiuYwA)

Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##1Va5jlQxEMznK17EitBHt@1gIYCEFBEgjUYCrQiQOKRlU/j1wa4qe4bVcohLoKd3tdvd1bffvrx5c3xxvLl3@fTD6wef7h@fX@4eXjx6f3396urm4uPFk3dX@j7sHj877vMWttKvvMUtHHZhJ0o87Pa@tf7l/W5bO@ziFxSs25Y6JffbF8cZ7TCkVexJkGqd7tJyohs4DXIr@FK/fMvgPNHToOxjf4@/vt7fsd8Jmm/T04G2ZNg2ntblhEGXlRGUwTcwGP4Hf4DGYWfrkoiI@gO@O4r0vT1jB/GOP@98DcgK9DbsddANngiwJIMjDj3Q8a29p53cFaQrw6/kHP8DYwTfiPLQWfEMuBv0GvgdPNTUo5l/VB6lUZaBWoRlUPAPxA220UsR/959ZNjrwFEUK@trSVdBPJk7AbIq4n2X/HgmMSOyjshVrdJnRd7LkB@gswBDgo0NNrriWM6iXOD7BAnz6cPa/POaqGHiDcDvyoeqnMiKNfPAkOkF/qwrklxh9SXojKC6vp15hXozePC2rizPN1nHLtBAyeAzaS9CX5UJCVliynvmVYNVCd@oM8hmzkfFMqorTIkR/L0btN@hd2r9us4zjfuZjQZvsOYKpCX5LSG2We@IvUUet@XdsLT5wnCSExEndsOGOBp4qdPB3bSa2WvsV7BNXKxq1kpFRY3eVJCxETwZfnV4r2nv7H0OnANvFDKiNFV8VcU41tmxEhDPmBVWirwy85nVQguq/NAQ1cj5Uf8@xomwwssBMcvq5QX@b6tifVlQFXWXtytsjMBqqzIdU4GRb@qtrq7YoKcCU4Ql1MBpZrIwiKOBHtSXg2zpnSiEfw3mHSD3HAKmkeAaYrZKYwbW1c5YYm0FoyqUprFh@C7ClISDSZJlRdQRoOrYENQ22MarSiqvhho301DHIYONYzr4f4AfCbq7O60wZNa@qo52zDMGq45pQ/s444gkqFO11ZFxTpQ9pj4/zwVF3S6sWcUZ6mu@8/xkmtlFM7Os5JtngH4SKX/KgrJFoW/L/0mJTK@mw2c). For each case this takes a third input containing the desired output. The footer code checks if the program output equals the desired output, and prints `Correct` or `Incorrect` accordingly.

#### How it works

Consider inputs `[1 2 3 2 3 2 4 1 2]` and `2` as an example.

```
t    % Implicit input: array A. Duplicate
     % STACK: [1 2 3 2 3 2 4 1 2], [1 2 3 2 3 2 4 1 2]
&=   % Matrix of pairwise comparisons
     % STACK: [1 2 3 2 3 2 4 1 2], [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
                                    0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1;
                                    0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0;
                                    0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1;
                                    0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0;
                                    0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1;
                                    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0;
                                    1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
                                    0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1]
R    % Upper triangular part: sets entries below the diagonal to 0
     % STACK: [1 2 3 2 3 2 4 1 2], [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
                                    0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1;
                                    0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0;
                                    0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1;
                                    0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0;
                                    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1;
                                    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0;
                                    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
                                    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
s    % Sum of each column. For each entry of A this gives the number
     % of repetitions up to that point
     % STACK: [1 2 3 2 3 2 4 1 2], [1 1 1 2 2 3 1 2 4]
i    % Input: number a
     % STACK: [1 2 3 2 3 2 4 1 2], [1 1 1 2 2 3 1 2 4], 2
>~   % Less than or equal? Element-wise
     % STACK: [1 2 3 2 3 2 4 1 2], [1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0]
)    % Apply as an index (logical mask)
     % STACK: [1 2 3 2 3 4 1]
     % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 13 bytes

```
(>:1#.]=]\)#]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NeysDJX1om1jYzSVY/9r/jdUSFMwUjBWsFAwVDBTMAHSRkBszGWEQxyk3kTHUMcECI3ApKmOOZBvDAA)

Comment: That's a totally novel way to evaluate cumulative self-count!

Comment: Indeed, really nice.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
fm≤⁰Sz#ḣ³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Py33UeeSR40bgquUH@5YfGjz////ow11jHSModhEB8iL/W8EAA)

```
f           # filter input to retain only elements at positions of truthy values of
 m≤⁰        # elements less-than-or-equal to arg 2 of
    Sz#     # count the occurrences of each element of arg1
       ḣ³   # in the list of prefixes of arg1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 17 bytes

```
0-.~]-1&(]*(-~:))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DXT16mJ1DdU0YrU0dOusNDX/a/43VEhTMFIwVrBQMFQwUzAB0kZAbMxlhF0cAA)

Apparently, this is shorter than a solution using Self-classify `=` or self equality `=/~`.

#### How it works

```
0-.~]-1&(]*(-~:))  NB. left: n, right: A
      1&(       )  NB. Apply this function on A, n times...
      1    (-~:)   NB.   Negation of Nub Sieve (mark first occurrence of each number)
         ]*        NB.   Multiply to A so that each first occurrence becomes 0
    ]-             NB. Kill (change to 0) survivors of ^ from the original A
0-.~               NB. Erase zeros by set difference
```

Illustration:

```
n = 2, A = 2 3 8 1 6 4 8 2 8 3
First iteration:
Nub sieve of A = 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
Kill them      = 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 2 8 3

Second iteration:
Nub sieve of ^ = 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
Kill them      = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0

Kill the survivors of ^ = 2 3 8 1 6 4 8 2 0 3
Erase zeros by set diff = 2 3 8 1 6 4 8 2 3
```

Comment: It looks like we both had a pretty similar approach!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 57 bytes

```python
lambda a,n:[e for i,e in enumerate(a)if a[:i].count(e)<n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFZboQwDIbfOYXfIJJbiX1ApRdhUJUyRhNNJyAWqS3i7NQJtKposyj2jx1/Md3HeG11uDbFeX2T99eLBIk6LwmatgeFBEoD6elOvRzJk0I1IMtcVY91O@nRI/Gkq3WkYXyRUIBXphjyzCqEMkIfU54RBugbIcGM3YR3tkUkGJtgjshY3pNONiq0yTF/Sowc27STFU2BBCMjB2wakV0@A95hJRyLow2Oj8ArsGu3hUPvHdUjXX54f9EGB84/lEfG@MgX/k9muOor1TfqTV33PAVpVLsI1vJDVzim49z8reefqvO2tiJs70H4Bhe5AzwGvqjxOENYt@sV/5DGneWCMOsFHp5hHhaY97IlFcVQLa5YvwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

```python
lambda s,n:reduce(lambda r,x:r+x*(r.count(x)<n),s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHbTsQgEIbv@xSTXoGOm5QedttYX2TdGOzSbI1OG8om1ZevA63GVOUQhp9/4AOGd3fpSc1t/Ti/6rfns4YRqbLmfG2MWBWLU2Vvpxthd01/JScmeU8SRzk7M7onDTWI4x5TruUJ4ZhhgnuuGSpMvFBgydOCe7k4Csy9mR0ly2vSIbjSkJzzUuHlPKQdgugPKDDzsuLQizzlUXFPTzIKOORxEgRuKrQ1lpGZBtM4c/7m/UGrNpy/KLeM@ZYv/ZvMc7W9BY2EBjqCj24Qy7shLMAIX2SyioCLVjXE8e6l70iMzgqSfgfy2VoGh/nfYRbHyLdshVZIMgrCYDty/LvA58V3DzH6mPepx/kT)

*-2 bytes from Leo by taking input and output as a string of digits, which is also used in the answers below*

---

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda s,n,r='':[x for x in s if(r:=r+x).count(x)<=n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFtb4MgEMff@ynuHZLdlogPrc3YF7FmYRZT040asImb8bO7A7tl6SoQ7v53Bz@P/nM4nk267e3Syv3yrj7eDgocGrSSsV01Qnu2MEJnwEHXxnYn7cPIn5rzxQzxyJ@lqZdBu@FVgYS42mBKo6wRqgwT3NDIUGDihQJLcgta5ZpRYO6TKaMk@Vq0DVlpKM4pVHg5D2XbIPoLCsy8LMj0Irm0C1ppzaOAYzxOgkBThHm1eaTHXjeDPvzy/qEVN5z/KG8Z81u@9D6Z52qOujlp6@9l@4vYZA1DCFaSMh75RitqvPbN/ur6eG0rwvo/CD/gfBcBfUpIqNxgY8PDIxlfp@oQ0/dieo05AmhjJdDw4Pe2o6ds2aRmhMnM8PgCk5thuvJWdJh09cz48g0)

Input and output as list of characters.

---

**55 bytes**

```python
f=lambda s,n:s and f(s[:-1],n)+s[-1][s.count(s[-1])>n:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHbToQwEIbveYoJV22c3YRy2IWEfZGGmLqUiNGB0JqoL4/TshqD2kOY@fmn/drO7/5xIrWuQ/tsXh56Aw6pcWCoh0E43RyyDkneOc2Bdsfr9EpexExeqOlWb52/N9CC0CfMudcdgi4wwxP3AhVmQaiw5rTiWW@OCstgZkfN8q3oHF15LC75VxXkMpadoxg2qLAIsuIwiJzyV/HMO5lEHAo4GQIPFcctlol9m@3V2/6b9wet2nH@otwzlnu@/G@ywDVMCxgktDASfIyz2O4NYQNG@CKTTQLcjGohTY9P00jC@UWQDCtQqDYyOuz/Drs5HJ9yEEbx@yVRmJeRPD8w8H7p4ZJiiHmd1q2f)

Repeatedly takes and removes the last element of the list, keeping it if it appears a maximum of `n` times in the current list.

It feels like there should be a better way to express this, but I'm not seeing it. Python is clumsy at dealing with the end of a list. While `l[-k:]` usually takes the last `k` elements from the end, for `k=0` it instead takes the whole list. So, I didn't find a nice single slice that conditionally takes 0 or 1 elements from the end of a list. Also, doing `l.pop()` has the trouble that the recursive function call comes before the expression where we want the last element.

Comment: You can save a `:` by taking a string of digits as input https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIUcnzypHITEvRSFNIyfaStcwVidPUzsnGsiIztFLzi/NK9EA8zTt8qxi/xcUZQIF0jSUTM3MLQzNjY3NTJR0DDU1/wMA

Comment: @Leo Nice idea, this also saves 2 bytes off my new solution

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 44 bytes

```hs
f n=foldl(\r x->r++[x|sum[1|y<-r,y==x]<n])[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDdboMwDIXveQpf7AJUc8FfWiToi2TRhGjY0NIMESrRiWcfszM2TWxyosQnx/GXvDTuVRuzrh3YunszFxM@jjDH5/FwkPPibleZLPcqHvFe17OqrIqkWiftpicDNUh5xIyiVAgyxwSPFDmmmLAgsKRU0Cy/HAILNpOjJHkrOnlX5osLOhIsF77s5EVuIDBnOaUti5TSmtLMlAo8jmWcBIFG6se2V4GeB91O@vLD@4s23XH@odwzFnu@7H8y5gpG7bgp/S0YWCA0aCOoYnjvB9j@cGMn87Xp@Q3D2NsJHiCkYgR/Qw3fT4jWj7YzzbNb43YYPgE)

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```powershell
$a,$b=$args
$t=@{}
$a|?{++$t.$_-le$b}
```

-1 byte thanks to *mazzy*!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzNCsIwEITveYocFtvQjZC0tvYQ9E0kldQfgpW24CHm2eNWCoIM3zLL7OxzeLlxujrv5XkYXYLehAQWoTNgx8vEYDbHEBnY9yEUBcxbOEnvoIspMpZvoOe5Qo3lSoW0Ca6FvA@3R4bZetNQUmEruPpPFO5ImlDfdo0NqcYW9yRFfpklsfhK8PL3IX0A)

Comment: ? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzNCsIwEITveYocFtvQjZC0tvYQ9E0kldQfgpW24CHm2eNWCoIM3zLL7OxzeLlxujrv5XkYXYLehAQWoTNgx8vEYDbHEBnY9yEUBcxbOEnvoIspMpZvoOe5Qo3lSoW0Ca6FvA@3R4bZetNQUmEruPpPFO5ImlDfdo0NqcYW9yRFfpklsfhK8PL3IX0A "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Comment: Oh, learning new tricks everyday, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 48 bytes

```r
function(x,n)x[diag(diffinv(outer(x,x,"=="))<n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDdDoIwDIXvfQqiN1tSL/aHLhFfxBBjFJQLR0LQ8PbYFhIHGLOMkZ5@7Wmbvime9bs4h/aR9eUrXNuqDqKDILvTrbrcxa0qyyq8Rf1qiwaFDtZZtpbyEGQeweIqdmDweAmJkskm2R5PFPH5apJlQcEOjwUNKsod4nqWnYLHaIrXc2U9ZkfxBeGoK9b3qE@ZSFm42nNFwy4c5qQTb1/VLVjHPvZM0gZSsBH7VQ3YGakxRgoS@Gq8JvI7V82PTVreI30ddlHMxxvVHJ@TNIVjjSoodkjb9NhnmGPwq/ifpjFjzf8kcTxl/wE)

Test harness taken from [Dominic's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219632/67312).

Closely related to [Luis Mendo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219635/67312), though implementing it in MATL is [longer](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v0TNNrI4IiXTrk7z//9oQwUjBWMoNlEA8mK5jAA). Rather than zeroing out the lower triangle of the matrix and computing the column sums, this calculates the cumulative sum of each column, then takes the diagonal of the resulting matrix as the filtering criterion -- for some element \$a_i\$ this tells the number of occurrences of \$a_i\$ before index \$i\$.

So for instance, using `[6,9,7,6,7,9,9]`:

```r
Pairwise equality check:
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0    1    1
[3,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0
[6,]    0    1    0    0    0    1    1
[7,]    0    1    0    0    0    1    1

Column-wise cumulative sum (with an initial condition of 0):
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    1    0    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]    2    1    1    2    1    1    1
[6,]    2    1    2    2    2    1    1
[7,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
[8,]    2    3    2    2    2    3    3
The diagonal:
[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
{x@&~y<+/'x=,\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VZLblQxENxzireCBSDkT3fbBCTuEdiGBVLWQYhcfbCryp4oQJCCQKDRzLxnt7urq3/@9PL64/XpdPX6y827p7ef3zx/9ezm7Yv3N19PV5dxlPHpF0f6cNwe860/ubqsRxrPcdQjH0l7XMtj148@nnx8@zyZ5@6dNUjY1DTO9LmzZe6swkrDqQLNNtZ92zrvGGQNuhskJ2I/qmTPO@WoQzKP//nm0JLHt8j@/Z0iTyv8nL82NKUpvz3OWJuSE4nhPWHHwdD0uwkXMSQ8D3Rl6nj41DxD1PPNh1wHuoDljrOOdQMjCf5USORpSVYeOn0@y3NJ1ioYpuR8nygz5Gbcp9WG34Rvh2WDvEOGlkZs60Lwa43UR22G1RCauYJ3YO7wj0xlvPvgyXDWgSQUMxt7RZ9AXJlJCbqaIv8jC/mOzooIOyLYtEveQgxWWEiwGkBR4GWHl65oxp1YB/gv0LB@R/TF12Nt0cZCnOCBKy@acqMq4swGQ9YHOG07ntxhPRbYzFh1PTvzi/krFu9bq@K/y0N2h46VCjmT/RD@pnwoyBVTBTC/OvwqeEbNQTezPyuiWZ1iacyQH12jT3y/b3nZ/bnVbROeMoMMfLD6AtqKuCuIb9V/xtkQ67YZTtuabwxnPRmxYo/siKVBljadPVu7lZ3HyMZj0S1krHDWTENtzU4VyNsMmQpmHfx1nV290IF0Is7CRpym2m@qHMc@u1cB4hW1YMWIl5XVrBl60MRER1zh48XROMn@LsqFsYHnhLhV9fZABPquXN8@NEXexXeDlxlYbVeoY0ow@l191tUhO@w0YMrwhBY44UweJkl0rCf16CRfRk9KGv//EtDvYILKgE0OCNdQs10gK7SuxsZC6zscTcE0DRHDcwhTEQ6mSZUXWReDputEUvNgS28qq7pba9aVhGwWto8zxf@DA5mwB@FlB6KyA6j26Me6dbD2mDihe15o2q9qqqoMWzdJ@WPq@OueEOp6ac8tTlTf8553KtMED83P2Om37gTjbhKT8z/jQ@g@aXteZcXHxGs5fQM)

Adapted from @rak1507's [message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57189397#57189397) in the APL Orchard. Takes the list as `x` and the number of occurrences as `y`.

- `+/'x=,\x` get the running totals of the counts of each number in the input
- `&~y<` get indices of the first `y` instances of each value
- `x@` index back into the input

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 62 bytes

```r
function(x,n)x[sapply(seq(x),function(i)sum(x[1:i]==x[i]))<=n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVBdi8IwEHy/X1G4lwT2HvJVzWH9I6WISMXCGT2rEn993d2Kpq1ISFNmdmZn99Sd6v3hWq/CeVd020vYnJtDEBGCjGW7Ph7/bqKt/0WU8CQb2V72Ipbqt6mKIpZNJeWiCFViJTZiBgaPl5ApmX1nP8uSEF99DaosKJjhsaBBJbU9rkfVOXhEc7yenfWjOsEnCkdd0d8jP9QkzCTVnB0Np3BYkw@yvVg30TrOMWclbSAHm2hfrAE7UmrEiEEFvhqvSfKOWfNmk5b3SF@HXRTr041qxsdKmsIxRw6KE9I2Pfbp5@jzKv6naczD87OSdDxldwc)

---

...although a port of [Luis Mendo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219635/95126) is shorter at <s>59</s> [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##fVDbisIwEH33KwqCJDAKuVUDdn9iH0VWKF1W0FRiK/XruzNTwbRdlpCmzLnMmYl9rK71o/oKzU/Rf7ehbM51EB0E2R3K@vLZXu@ivd2quGniWTz367ptqoiEDk5FcZJy9ZT7cExsRCm2YPB4CZmS2TJbfxyo4o@LEcuCgi0eCxpUwh3qesLOwWM1x@vZWb/YSX2mcNQV/T3iY02CzFLt2NFwCoecfJTtjbqZ1nGOHStpAznYRPtGDdiJUmONEFTgq/GaJO8UNX9s0vIe6euwi2J9ulHN9amSpnCMkYPihLRNj32GOYa8iv9pGvPy/F9JOp6y/wU) (*Thanks to Giuseppe*)

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##fVDbisIwEH33KwqCJDAKuVUDdn9iH0VWKF1W0FRiK/XruzNTwbRdlpCmzLnMmYl9rK71o/oKzU/Rf7ehbM51EB0E2R3K@vLZXu@ivd2quGniWTz367ptqoiEDk5FcZJy9ZT7cExsRCm2YPB4CZmS2TJbfxyo4o@LEcuCgi0eCxpUwh3qesLOwWM1x@vZWb/YSX2mcNQV/T3iY02CzFLt2NFwCoecfJTtjbqZ1nGOHStpAznYRPtGDdiJUmONEFTgq/GaJO8UNX9s0vIe6euwi2J9ulHN9amSpnCMkYPihLRNj32GOYa8iv9pGvPy/F9JOp6y/wU) on the port.

Comment: @Giuseppe - Thanks - although your own ```diag``` version is much better...

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>23</s> 19 bytes

Saved a couple bytes by looking at Bubbler how negated the mask in [their answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219640/95792).

```apl
{⍺/⍨(⊢∨(≠⍺×~))⍣⍵⊢0}
```

Don't [try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR7279B/1rtB41LXoUQeQ6lwAFDk8vU5T81Hv4ke9W4HiBrX//xsqGCkYA7EJGJuAecZAOk3BGAA) because TIO has an older version of Dyalog APL without Unique Mask.

Takes the array on the left and n on the right.

This takes advantage of monadic `≠`, which gives a mask to obtain unique elements. While `≠A` lets you keep unique elements in `A`, the mask `1-≠A` inverts it and lets you keep only repeated elements in `A`. Then `A×1-≠A` replaces unique elements with zeroes (this is safe because as the question states, `A` only contains numbers 1-9). The mask `≠A×1-≠A` gives us only unique elements from this new array, but since we replaced unique elements, it lets us keep duplicates (and the first element, but that is always kept no matter what anyway). `(≠A)∨≠A×1-≠A` now gives us a mask for unique elements and duplicates, but not triplicates, etc. By repeating this process `n` times, we get a mask for keeping only n-plicates, and then we just apply that mask to `A` to get the result.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
œ&Qx¥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVVLjhUxDLwKC8QqErIT28kZWLFET7NkM5oDwJYrcAbEhlOAuAgXecTl6syMWt2vO3HKrvLnPX5@evp6v//9/u7jl98/7n9@vv/w9t@3X5/u99stWt/XemhvZN@322jSYl@jaZOz6m3tNd/3gq1y1fLstl1773l9tAn7Dizb@36QDCgTO@nZ2zh7ur9zZ6/tX913f4EpezWjyqft04LdOil7xfaewUrgI@NdG6N85TPjyff02HEud32fW/CZmPmeWI51AxNBLAMWmhivzg9wrZP5nXEoTqWKiTPxFNwLWAZ7h015TvXGwUyrwLq10l7JSPHtm4uBjQMvqIztvc4roGLpL8CaLzKXekxgKXkGGQ@cFiAGPHQwW2Dm4BjAvfQOKNaBcD13Bg4jQbROHSe1HFS3tDfkPsB1HrVqp6qsIzbFqvPdKx8N@T/sFlAHEIzYQQ6TuenIW/GezMwCn453Q30aonNoNKhJ1fSFqLDP@l70XbkxcK3KCuB1Rtqh@uCvAiHI0Q4fOV6LRdBj4SiUqf5aUM5gWz4d1ou7gxVviC@Qd4WfAQYO1otZvLrFgZnYSpRCrKwHPZY2wR7qYH4pE1UFZHBlu2quGE7GvJANaLVjnIxTOUWqxvycnFTGqdIEtoKHnXrJ9U51FrvU2UcLfifiVbAsDzV1jOyFFgvrwg4X8szqFmGoAefVps5BZSdBl6zOMq5E11gZSJ6ypJUN60y4goqdAg2mYbLZA82kDDbYxB32cVqgGs84FDFWq4yfKXRUt3C6llrCfwI/M7JyVDkpytXtFZywBtfpO4G7wfqUQ7smW9WxnL6vaeJnjtVMr8x2ICn9TnbMOv9d8fAf)

Accidental translation of Razetime's Stax answer based on his comment.

```
œ&       Multiset intersection of A with
  Q ¥    the unique elements of A
   x     repeated n times.
```

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
xċṪ$Ƥ<¥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVVLjhUxDLwKi1m2hOzEdiJxA06AnmbJBs0BYMuWa4CQEBdgOyDuARdp4nJ1ZlCr@3UnTtlV/rx3bx8ePpzn@1@f/vz4dvf786vHL@fPry9f3/39@P3Ned5ucbR1zfvjhaz7duuHHLGufughe9WPudZ83RO2ylXLs8t2rr2n9X4M2Ddg2dr3jWRAGdhJz370vafrO3fW2vrVdbdnmLJWM6p82jot2K2TslZs7RmsBD4y3rkwylc@M558T48N53LX17kJn4mZ74nlWDcwEcTSYaGJ8d/5Dq51Mr8zDsWpVDFxBp6CewLLYO@wKc@pXt@YaRVYt6O0VzJSfPviYmDjwAsqY2uv8QqoWPoLsMazzKUeA1hKnkHGHacFiAEPDcwmmDk4BnAvvQOKNSBcz5WBzUgQrVPHQS071S3tDbkPcB1brdqpKmuITbHqfPfKx4H8b3YTqB0IRuwgh8HcNOSteA9mZoJPw7uhPg3ROTTq1KRq@kJU2Gd9T/qu3Bi4VmUF8BojbVC981eBEORom49sr8Ui6LFwFMpUf00oZ7Atnw7ryd3OijfEF8i7wk8HAwfrySxe3eLATGwlSiFW1oMeS5tgDzUwv5SJqgIyuLJdNVcMB2OeyAa0WjEOxqmcIlVjvk8OKuNUaQBbwcN2veR6ozqTXersowm/A/EqWJaHmjpG9kKLiXVhhwt5ZnWLMNSA82pT56CynaBLVmcZV6JrrHQkT1nSyoZ1JlxBxXaBBtMw2OyBZlIGG2ziBvvYLVCNZxyKGKtVxk8UGqpbOF1LLeE/ge8ZWTmqnBTl6vYKTliDc/edwF1nfcqmXZOt6lh239c08T3HaqZXZhuQlH4HO2bu/664/wc)

I was going to hold off on posting until I tied caird's 6 bytes, but I feel like I'm so far off the mark that it's worth documenting anyhow.

```
x     ¥    Repeat each element of A by the corresponding elements of:
    Ƥ      for each prefix of A,
 ċ         how many times it contains
  Ṫ$       its last element (which is then not considered).
     <     Is each count less than n?
```

Comment: In hindsight, this is an obvious improvement on my original 8 byte version, so I’ve definitely +1’ed. As a clue tho, my 6 byte version has a completely different approach

Comment: you might be able to use the same approach I did with `œ&`.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 157 bytes

```
l->n->java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0,l.length).filter(i->java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0,i+1).filter(j->l[j]==l[i]).count()<=n).map(i->l[i]).toArray()
```

Takes a `int[]` and the integer `n` as input and returns a `int[]`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVA9b4MwEN35FTfarbFKk6atEpC6VOrQiRExuASoqTHIPlJFUX47PSBq1K16er7zfTzfuVEHFTb7r1G3fecQGrrLAbWR1WAL1J2VN9sg6IcPowsojPIe3pW2cAoALlGPCskcOr2HlnIsRadtneWgXO35XArwetHbaYtZLuDN4t9QkkAF8WjCxIbJdQ6PrlStpPJ08ZyydcnuhJGmtDV@cllpg6Vj@l9t@jb67WjCxGRNHscm0zmXRTdYZHwXWy5b1U@CSwK7F@fUkfFxO@@SHj2WrewGlD2tisay68tzqaee5RtYJVXfmyOz5TfMi54i8UC4J0ZiTdyIR8JGPIsnQkT@dK6Ik78@84vCinM@DXAOzuMP)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! It's recommended to link to an online playground. I'd suggest using TIO; [here](https://tio.run/##jVA9b4MwEN35FTfarbFKk6atEpC6VOrQiRExuASoqTHIPlJFUX47PSBq1K16er7zfTzfuVEHFTb7r1G3fecQGrrLAbWR1WAL1J2VN9sg6IcPowsojPIe3pW2cAoALlGPCskcOr2HlnIsRadtneWgXO35XArwetHbaYtZLuDN4t9QkkAF8WjCxIbJdQ6PrlStpPJ08ZyydcnuhJGmtDV@cllpg6Vj@l9t@jb67WjCxGRNHscm0zmXRTdYZHwXWy5b1U@CSwK7F@fUkfFxO@@SHj2WrewGlD2tisay68tzqaee5RtYJVXfmyOz5TfMi54i8UC4J0ZiTdyIR8JGPIsnQkT@dK6Ik78@84vCinM@DXAOzuMP)'s a link. You can use currying to save a byte, and you can omit the semicolon at the end.

Comment: Also, you need to either include the import for `IntStream` or use `java.util.stream.IntStream` instead (the TIO link I pasted above does the latter). However, [here](https://tio.run/##ZU/BaoQwEL37FXNMigbsbrdbXIVeCj30tEfxMHV1iY2JJKNFxG@30S4tpTxe8jIZ3rxpcMCouXwssu2MJWj8W/Qklah7XZI0WtwlQdD170qWUCp0Dt5QapgCgFvVEZK/BiMv0Po/diYr9TUvAO3V8a0V4OXmd5Ka8iKEV01/S1kGNaSLijIdZdOAFjD9jfNsLY5OOLIVtkzxxFbUWw0oaqmoskxG2Y9uokymacNFaXpNjJ9SzUWL3dqkcllwQWYzZHxeki3eeXRUtcL0JDqfnpRm/4aT@d6M1QK7To1MV5@wZZ/i8MHj3jMO956H8NHjED6FR4/Y6/Xcea56P/Obw45zvgaYg3n5Ag)'s a shorter approach by turning `l` itself into a stream.

Comment: @user Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user That approach doesn't work because the stream can only be consumed once.

Comment: @iota Oops, you're right. It's unordered too, so [this](https://tio.run/##jU9Na4QwEL37K@aYlBiwu91u2VXopdBDT3sUD6mry9iYSDJukcXfbqMVSumlPF4yma@816iripvzx4RtZx1BE96yJ9Sy7k1JaI28O0RR179rLKHUynt4U2jgFgGsWU@KwnW1eIY21NiJHJpLXoByF8@XVoCXdd8RDeWFgFdDv1NZBjWkk44zE2c/Op6dU4OXnlylWqa5rFFT5Rj@p6mJM0zThsvS9oYYP6aGy1Z187TOseCS7DLL@HRYZJ4GT1UrbU@yCy5IG/bnG7LfDlktVdfpgZnqExYPt0Q8BNwHJmIbuBOPATvxJPYBSYjncxM4x9uRrxs2nPNZwBiN0xc) won't work either :(

Comment: No need for Streams :) [101 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220356/94107)

Comment: According to OP's rules, you can in and output whatever's convenient, so you can [output an IntStream](https://tio.run/##jVDBboMwDL3zFT4mW4jG2nWbWpB2mbTDThwRh4wCCwsBJaZTVfXbmWGoO/QyWS9x/OxnO406qLDZf4267TuH0NBbDqiNrAZboO6svNkGV6RHV6p2ooJ@@DC6gMIo7@FdaQunAGCJelRI16HTe2iJYyk6bessB@Vqz@dUgNel1U5bzHIBbxYvIfLTuVmSQAXxaMLEhsnVJJc06ZStS3YnjDSlrfGTy0obLB3T/yrTt9GlogkTkzV5HJtM51wW3WCR8V1suWxVPwnOxLidt0iPHstWdgPKnpZEY9lfvxfn1NFL7H4/gFVS9b05Mlt@w7z1KRIPZPeESKwJG/FIthHP4oksIn86V4TJX5/5orDipDrLM875NMo5OI8/) and skip the toArray() for -10.

Answer (score 3):

## [**T-SQL**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference?view=sql-server-ver15), 114 bytes

`SELECT C FROM (SELECT B,C,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY C ORDER BY B) AS D FROM @A) E WHERE D <= @n ORDER BY B;`

Example:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE(B INT IDENTITY(1,1), C INT);
DECLARE @n INT;
INSERT INTO @A SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(2),(3),(2),(4),(1),(2)) AS A(C);
SET @n = 2;

SELECT C --4.Finally select the filtered rows
FROM (SELECT B
            ,C
            ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY C ORDER BY B) AS D --1.Create an ordinal for each repetition that increments in ascending order of B
      FROM @A
      ) E 
WHERE D <= @n --2.Filter on the windowed function in subquery, removing rows with more than n repetitions
ORDER BY B; --3. Preserve original order of table variable @A (Can't order by in subquery)
```

Returns:

|  | C |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 1 |

Only way I could simulate an 'array' was by making a table with an identity on insert to store the insertion order.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, nice first answer!

Comment: @Redwolf Programs Thanks. I'm gonna try and sneak a T-SQL answer in wherever I can :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 52 bytes

```
\d+$
$*
(.)(?=.*,(.)+)(?<=(?(2)$)(?<-2>\1.*)+.)|,.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HZM5jhNREIbzPscg2ePGUu1VEsOEXIIAJAhICBAhdzdf2bKt1361/Jv//Pz76/f3x4fLl2@Prz9uL8fL63G5Xy/vb/fXk8ON46e3y/tFry97/Kifv8r99Xq7X/@d99vxeJTZnHK4VLkKp5zKmjn1yLDxyT16T5lUeFIRWS30pfOg1pLe2rZl4q7uUWJcSYSGuGRVTtPSYiLlpx3dqZNeohORqdEj2u6lIs9rn73rDtWhJbMzJWW0QzSl6J3TKRwtrwC0skVz0kIktWHjMcarvAEuXr2cWjpHWUh1uJm4lqRNT2h2Vz0xV4RV7juLNWKR4AMW5HpAHtY11YuJB4SyQL5MvhMOUGfZzHhKUFzMb5iYD5tpmwnEmCiLgb@CT9F3C9UkzzmWSShNuBHoJpbjttiNOtDyk2wnG8qeNZqOSWOo5nRmGdqNo3gcJa0qPp0hA721IxuFlArqoF30gQVh0O0JpaDP/OWMauxrBo/xybOPUlKBWLl3GIovku0MiVhNspmBsmQId0a9zTSGBvISvVYQPm/BaWFlnSIHLgZmstRj2SxS7KGQTnWDViILlsNaw2LFLBgADQYEURAY4xrdfP1R8gpUQ99dYM4@d1CRxcoNInwgwmIMZxpaABnfpHYhesVmkD@AytpOQHLDhclwtSJNtVw3bnPWfw) Link includes test cases. Takes `A` as a string of digits and `n` as a positive integer separated by a comma. Explanation:

```
\d+$
$*
```

Convert `n` to unary.

```
(.)(?=.*,(.)+)(?<=(?(2)$)(?<-2>\1.*)+.)|,.+
```

Delete any digit of `A` that is preceded by at least `n` identical digits and also delete `n` from the result.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-al`, 28 bytes

```perl
$l=<>;map$k{$_}++<$l&&say,@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lx9bGzjo3sUAlu1olvlZb20YlR02tOLFSx8Ht/39DBSMFYyg2UQDyuIz@5ReUZObnFf/X9TXVMzA0@K@bkwgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 38 bytes

```ruby
->a,n{w=[0]*10;a.reject{|x|n<w[x]+=1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LCsIwEEX3fkXXOkonLxs0/kjIokq7cFGkKK20/fZ4k4W0DDeBczKX9J/7N7YuHm81ddPgfBn2XF7qU988m8d7mse5uw5@DAfHyxJfReu9IqYzRpEgDlRw2GVuyIIaxJIFF3@uSYIpxGyMoirvyNyo8cKs@nTuqrKTGENqZQVIcqC4BSI3zQyefphOjQbOnkP8AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

```
fVÆâÃc 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/Py3scNvhRYebkxWM/v@PNtOx1DHXMQNiSx3LWB0FIwA) or [Check all test cases](https://tio.run/##1VZbilQxEP2fVfQCrmAelaQQF@HH6EDTHyI6IAh@uAPBhbiVWVibnHOS24w6woiiNPd2bqVSdeqd968/fjpfXd@GZzfPr2/js@v@fnp@9/Luy93Xu89vDvF88/bV@Xg81i31n5@2Q9gO@PLT6ep4zFvYav/lLW5Bu6RF7JfN@7r0x3E69v0LmnhsyOsyvFN3rguqdDWcTJBvfacsjfuOidugoYF3YC9bFve@kzpt8Ma@Gt@dp//H/iShuL@TltUZNo@3dWkBJ6b1ETTyDkQGyjgToHtY710e0RFJwHpgTF3Kw6fGmYl9fJfO6cBYod1xuoBu8E2AVRkcceiSnodO72d5Lix9Gd4m7/geSCM4RyYMvQ3vgMeh28BfwENdI9JZGH4tkfIozUCtC8@ggQLcDhvpr4jv0r1lOF2ApSp21veSfhURZl4FyGrKgR9piBcysyJdEMmmfXqvyo8ZOgL0VuBIsNRhaVFU60XMK6KQIGG@exbIZ4/VRR075gArivKjKUeyIs@sMNRAhV/biip3WKMJWiOoRevCPENFmjx5X1tWDFw2zq7hoGVwmhBU2dCUFwk5Y6oG5pnDtoQ1KhDSWQdRcY3qHlNiBP/oJN4R/r7mqffnWnedtJWZZPAJK7FCXpL/EqKc9R9xusrztrwclr6yUOxyIuLFzumIp4GXOgu4XbtZfcjgj8eim8hY66ydhhpj36rI3wiuDO8W@NB1evbGAqwDcxQ6IjX1gaYKKthnL0vAPCNXWTnyzMxt1g5taPKFI7awstvfMOn@LsqJscHTAZHLq9dXRMFXDZdlRVP0i3zeYGcEWluVWjA3mAGurlvULR2aGlBF2EINnHsmG4M4HPSgjh1kzehOgReEfwno9zDpzAqtHBdFY85WmczwFrU4lpuvkDQF1DRSDOsqVElImCpZdkRdF5quGUFNhO29qbjyarJxM41@XErYRnYn/w8GRMKGy9MKRmYnUAXSknkTYQUyeWgh5x@xBHUuXz0at01ZZOr98@ZQ1f3CmmGcr2XNf960TBO9aprWlYLzjjBuK7V7/c/YULco/L5ikJTQ9Gyf16fDkxcfvgE)

Very similar to the Jelly, Stax, and Husk answers.

Explanation:

```
            # Implicitly store the input array as U and the input number as V
 VÆ         # Create an array of length V
   âÃ       #  Each item in the array is the unique elements of U
     c      # Flatten that array
f           # Only keep elements of U that are in that array...
       2    # ... up to the number of times it appears in that array
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 56 bytes

```cs
(a,n)=>{var b=new int[10];return a.Where(c=>b[c]++<n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVHBasMwDL33K3xMqBeWuLZn0uQyOhjstkMPJQfHqCyQudRJtkLpt2eymsF@YBhb1tN78hN2w4Mbuvll8m7b@fHQcDz5685PnxBs20NE65odWcXmxHKfVvX1ywbWVh6@WZTkj00ZYJyCZzbbf0CAxFV1e3DNer31aXljc7mKEhsCdvmVNewq@IbnuAqMG/6E21CucSnMFVYMovE0iEnCJRcUFTIjX5LeUC6poyZEYAdJHEk8jZhGNL6XU1UjXhBHkUIu/ST1VPROQYy7H0EeDEbBza1c0VQeZ9LLHS5/B/yn@aKn@2yGFGLJo09FNxG9PZ/8cOoh24duhLfOQ3JM8AfwB7N3OE/gHezOk@0TuKRpOf8A)

Or 66 bytes if output should explicitly be an array vs an enumerable:

```cs
(a,n)=>{var b=new int[10];return a.Where(c=>b[c]++<n).ToArray();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVHBasMwDL33K3xMqBeWuLZn0gTG6GCw2wY9lBycoLJA5lAn2TpKvz2T1Q76A8PYsp6enp9wM9w1Qzs/T65Zt27cVRxP/rJx0yd4W3cQ0LJke1awObLcxUV5@rKe1YWDbxZa0vsq9zBO3jGbbD/AQ9QUZb1rquVy7eLkvX/03v5EcX5mc74IzdZ71PsTqNhJ8BVPcWUYV/wBt6Fc41KYK6wYRMNpEJOESy4oKmQGvqR@Q7kkRU2IQAVJHEk8jZhGNLyXUlUjnhFHUYe86knSVPRORoyLH0EeDEbBzTlf0FQOZ9LXOxxvB/yn@YKny2yGOsQ1Dz4V3UTw9tS7oe8g2fp2hNfWQbSP8AfwL5M3OEzgGtgcJttFcIzjfP4F)

Comment: The first one is fine, if you wanna display it in TIO when using the interactive compiler, just use the `Print` function

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##tVHBasMwDL33K3xMqBeWuI5r0vgyOhjstkMPJQfHqCyQudRJtkLpt2ey2sJ@YBhbes/vyRJ2w5Mbuvl18m7T@XHf8EfK37Z@@oJg2x4iNsawA6vZbGvja3P5toG1tYcfFn35c1MFGKfgmc12nxAgcbVp965ZLjc@ra5srhbRYkPAIg9bwy6Cr3iOq8C44mvcmrDCVSIu8UYjG0@NnCReckGxRGXUS/JrwpIqKmIEVpCkkaRTyClk43s53SrkC9KU5JD3epJqlvROQYpbP4J60BgF19dqQVN5nEndczj/HfCf5os93WbT5BB3HPssKROxt5ejH449ZLvQjfDeeUgOCf5Amvg0@4DTBN7B9jTZPoFzmlbzLw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
ＮθΦη‹№…ηκιθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcvLCoJAFIDhfU/h0gFbnNucObgUgiCiVzARlMy7QU8/TYt/88HfdPXaTPUQ43Wcj/1@vJ/tmi@uPD3WftzzSz/sCboiu7XbllfTkbD6NkNbddP895crsj61OOfKGPVEDIDMgQ1A1QePxmimol5IvQcDQTYPwqDIFARMDJSVAIGCGgp45GQigp4UMb2BVIzI4vkz/AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input `n` as an integer and `A` as a string of digits. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ          Input `n` as an integer
   η        Input `A`
  Φ         Filtered where
     №      Count of
         ι  Current character in
      …ηκ   Prefix so far
    ‹       Is less than
          θ Input `n`
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>46</s> 43 bytes

```julia
l$n=(j=0;!i=sum(l[1:(j+=1)].==i)<=n;l[.!l])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VbbbhMxEH3PV5ioD7tiVeG7TVl@JOQB0a2UalmqZCv1P5B44uv4kWCfGXvTUopUBIJGSXfH45kzZy729e24ey/vjsfxbOqb6/7VxYtdf7j92Iwb@bq5ftnLdnve97v2TT9djJvzF@O2Pc7DYT6IXmxWzcZ3On3ithOyFf1bAUHcphXTyc6nj@lUJ5d1Equs4bqYHl36RlhQpHEiJi2bTSY7MQnv6Z0skMeArRoubFpwp36XRUv6Fk4CtHMUrjOL/rKokzhpq/SQX5NW@q/SVy9YHi7qwoBB/PnXJnMSe06YUBBDO8OyEORdEu4zDTEZJIwERuI5I9Vk5@mNeRtHkF9dUoyA6eE@YrOD3IIiidgMNFT2tnh6ysCynbbK4tGAdlLN7xmqgmKujew54FfiG@HdQt9Bh1zlvJsFxa@NkkkyaCH1BVEWQQDgEXESZQrvLhFmsdkBjecc2rSm@eORaKoyCVthqYbHnKgTs4Yy7pDRwMtEoGcqDbxIePZAohFqRKiOU@tPEu@RCA0L5TeVwsLbc92Rm4paIgzHdRK4Vgynn0rDoh08uA01t7RCTavhVEHq@NlRvaFB7cLmQ4eGUxE5UJ4mESIDRcsYPAcRuDg0CsdyW1C9RQSn8YxmhHHqCMXZVTxRikUF/TxdImH8fefF9c8dL24RLZWTBSnUkh7mNHOokWjD/xU2e2bfVqZldecqiMWOQs5onkbk1EKXfDpoR141PJVsYeS5AAs4anzqoYB2wxTzKGIFJQN6HUiMvLnMSge0GbVifITV8kAI3EkO6zTWNCCX1HnqIOamVDg1EIUQmI2I5CLIxEAoJ@HfBVpgBnAtkT5TZr9HGmJtZVfjCFwBjkkPiFQBrK0d63CMUBVEHsCOJ2eEowBQCqGQBzoKLYcoWSNCLnl4Sw4mzylZrxD/EtYfkYJOD6d0eDg@9WxtlpJfx8OOmi7WnATOqOUDxuLZMyjNQKhWDIeh@BIR@PoheZLQqA/cX6aOW9VZvgvgskKz5B7N/0MMipBn0nXNhqFxwH1IgZSrCfUhVQ8FSKchQZE8wWId1biOckCWT4FykfA8BWU9z@i0dfU@QJcvy8e754PV1xosd4Z8f/HE@58Jw3eKQ4g1C5qLmrhNp/d2tbr6tBez2E0Ct/iVSH9NM3ZT24kh4RMzRPv0NIozMeFtd5UFvRjwlv9u9rtpHqdm/e3rZ7HuBCzk6PYtdIbx8Kjyl/vKnVi/m5vh7mb4MA@X4mxo17x/ulzl7@r4HQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 62 bytes

```c
f(*l,n){for(int m[10]={0};*l;++l)m[*l]++<n&&printf("%d ",*l);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzLCoMwEEX3@YpBUPIY0YjQRWx/JGQhlhRhjEWyC/n2NG25m7M45279Rmt4leK5JAwi@fPie4hwWD26exqzkWSUInFYSU6pJXTd@6qG5037hAYlCZPLN4m2BjNqvNXNOFWqOfu9rXsALhIDzyOCBmGGoX@A/euTY7l8AA)

- Expects a 0 terminated array as input

If tacking a 0 filled array as an additional input is valid:

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 58 bytes

```c
f(*l,n,*o){for(int m[10]={0};*l;++l)m[*l]++<n&&(*o++=*l);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LCoNADEX3fkUQKjNJxAdCF1P7I4MLsbUMjGOx7sRvn8Zasgn3nhwy5IPvwyvGUaHnwDjrbZwX5cIKk63Krt3K3aA3RF5PFn1HdAtZpnAmatFrs8eDXa2QDVd8lWm4lk3ukqNanh8R/U2/ZOpdAKW3BEa1MlTAwmhTFPkd7CmpOynPP9BBK71BZxyRfi@SjaDSywNSRqdNsscv)

Comment: [-6 Bytes](https://tio.run/##LY7LCoMwEEX3fsUgFJLJiA@ELtL0R4ILsU0JxKRYd@K3p2MtsxnuPXOYqZrCGF85O4GBImGSm0uL8HGF2bbNYLZm15gMBp2UmS0GpQalblHqPR/UapnpqaUrT08db3xRHNXy/LDi7/gl8@gjCLkV4MRK0AIxI3VdV3ewp6QbuDw/QA@Ge41ee6Xke@HMgSgvDygJvdTFnr8) for the seconds solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 54 bytes

```hs
f n|let a?x|sum[1|y<-a,y==x]<n=a++[x]|1>0=a=foldl(?)[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLLboMwELz3K7Y@gdgoNa8EKU5@oD310IOLKkuFJgqBCEhLJP87XduJoJVlbM/Mzi5e71V3LKpqHEuodVX0oHaD7i4nyfV1s1B4FWLIN7VQQSCHXPPtk1CibKrPytv5Mh9P6lCDgJM6v3zA@dK/9u1zDZKVwILA6/bND1SHrvchCIAhMLM6uO73Dn0ng@2caYsOfMPAcunw76K9SRlo8IwjUjwWw9nfLKQnVxjRyHIEDgj2mOU@PgB4MkaOKxoxhsjvCgeGd02KGR1Tmpl1CQHn2CRLjDNZZURMwhk6ZV3b@MgmSohMXe4/TDIFJDbV2srNz6QY34udqIjAmz6kg4FIR2tIM7rV85@J5jcR23sw34Q8uQ1yVXHCDUZywsxbMI0QUJpW2S46lJqhHSWAGkAK1hyZBnobZv/WNvXXI8vHXw)

- I was on the right track, one big step behind @xnor answer which cost me 10 bytes!

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 76 bytes

```clj
#(for[[i v](map vector(range)%1):when(<(count(filter #{v}(take i %1)))%2)]v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDbbsMgDH3PV1iqKhmJl5D7tD9BPEQpbNky6GiaVpr27ZlnyiYsA@eGxbSEt2u0O56sA7cf0IWo9QybwY/xDJud1hAxjv7FimMpnm6v1uMzTuHqV3TzstoIh6/tG9fx3cIMpBHiqITZxC4KPIWL/dT6Lr0BDYXWnYSKazASSkNITbuEjovO6hd@UC3JGG@5D8mlHlSTctg1sOaPJaTP3irnN6xsc3iTY/ssSIMRWGeNYiQJWrb3PCH16v@tUta0FPdGdnSvUoAxBZ7j7NfFAzq4g6fP2X8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>31</s> 28 bytes

```
nFold[#||Count@##<n&&#2&]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVXLihsxELzvbwyYBCYHtaSWBEkwBHIO5Gh8MJssu5D1QnBOXu9H5A/yhfkEp1Vd0gZ7xjNSq7qr@uHHw@n@@@Ph9HB7uN59uB7//v7z@enHt93y/Pzp6dfxtF2W98fNZpHN/vrl58PxtFvefXxzt1tkv102b7fbZb95@Xp7OL6cb87nsMoaeaXV3i79axvFluLaLmvAa98r9klmF8airs2W1K7WLYWLuR80y2ZbczmtFdYRQNm2dcBkQFRsdKe6prHVA@sbtmS/Yld8BQy2mBB3MsBi73GcC7aQbSvDKMBBj7QZgjvq9x5LfzZ3Ecf6ptqxBocdsT93KMV6BomAQBIspEP8fzyBpR/s7z0KwaEuXoepuAdcDVAZ9gobd2yypQnZjQqW8@qSC@kI3tWIZFBRwBWqkm0v8lMgoAsfgFVfE9a1qIASkiykm3A4ALDAQQSvBl4KhgWwQ@sCuSIQxt3UH3wCYlVqWKljorKue0bSC5jWKZXveG1FhCZYVT6r52JF6ge3BtAEgEzoQgaVeYnImbOuzEoDm4jnjLLMCE6hUKIiXskDUWBvVd3o2vOSwdRrqgAuMs4IyRN/BQCFDPNkE6ZTJ1Ho0HEEunhTNeiWYes@FdaNu8lLPbO/A0wEXBqYZ/D1DI4uUUA2DIjCcBsCEQRTWQmKfW@eCOJDl@IVQAIj1V5vTrAy5IZcQKpLr0@EKRwcXl46D1bqotSoAlpAI89a6euR2jS2p7KDGtxWhCsg6R581GSSD7RoWA9s7UCaVtghMNIC396fyumUZ3aGqMoK9iz7NEnInLCahZ2qzLaASZ7FWZiEyi4v6CNhrIXtG2FfZvl7z2WOQoxSL@HJIKKwAyeqaxU493VORk@QZ8QZe5t7bIH112bLBXhLrM0wWftE8xoOs@N9jOicXz7IPa8RSEK/ld3Sxh9Vudxcrv8A)

Returns an `Or` of digits. Input `[n][A]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 87 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
	T =TABLE()
R	I =INPUT	:F(END)
	T<I> =T<I> + 1
	OUTPUT =I LE(T<I>,N)	:(R)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NPwdbTLyA0hIszRME2xNHJx1VDkyuI0xMqzGnlpuHq56IJlLbxtAOqAJHaCoZcnP6hIUB5oDIFoBaQsI6fJqeVRpAmF1D9//9GXGZcllzmQNIcSFsCAA)

Takes input as `N`, then `A`, each element separated by newlines.

```
	N =INPUT			;* Read in N, number to keep
	T =TABLE()			;* create an empty table
R	I =INPUT	:F(END)		;* read in the next input; if none exists, exit
	T<I> =T<I> + 1			;* increment the value at index I (initially 0)
	OUTPUT =I LE(T<I>,N)	:(R)	;* if T<I> is LEQ to N, then output I. Goto R.
END
```

Answer (score 1):

## **[Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 66 Bytes**

```
def f(A,n):[A.pop(-A[::-1].index(i)-1) for i in A if A.count(i)>n]
```

There are already superior Python answers to this, but thought it's worth a mention as it only uses list methods.

Comment: An answer must be a function or a full program. Yours is a snippet because it assumes the input is already stored in the variable `A`, so it is invalid. You can make it a function by adding `lambda A:` to the start. Also, please use the permalink feature on TIO. (You can find the Code Golf post formatter there too.)

Comment: you need to submit this as a function for it to be valid. your Try it online link is also empty.

Comment: Changed it to a function. Removed the try it online as I need to wrap my head around how to use it. Not sure this answer is valid as it mutates list A to the desired form, but the function itself returns None.

Comment: Mutating the input list is [definitely a valid output form](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/46076)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 101 bytes

```java
l->n->{for(int i=0,j,c;i++<9;)for(j=c=0;j<l.size();)j+=l.get(j)==i?++c>n?l.remove(j)*0:1:1;return l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVFNT8MwDD23v8LHhHbZCuNjy1rEBQkJThwRh9CmU0qaVok7NKb99uGySUgcELKcvDjP9ovTqI2aNNX7wbR95xEaOosBjRX14Eo0nRNnMo774c2aEkqrQoAnZRzs4ugUDKiQtk1nKmjpij2jN2798grKrwMfmdH9qdjqp/6d92r7aAKuHhzqtfZFCoT@xSwKqCGHg50UblLs6s4z4xBMPkubtJQmSVYLycdwk5f5TDYrK4L51IxL3iS5FWuNrOF5bm6TpCzcrRVet91GU/BstsyWmfQaB@/Ayv1BxtFfYgB1QFLj9Af8xaPmcUSa4KgVlt8ZhGlSuyy9JDsnz9I5@VV6TXaVLtIbsozwuF6Qj3i@5zTUsa9QVcUMlzCdwjh4rdoAR@0BBtd2lamNerOaEp63AXUrugFFTz@E1rFfeoPA7vh7jOpHtVB9b7dsbMRP@GLsHBHvO4FxTq8C2Mf7wxc)

Input: `ArrayList<Integer>`

Output: `ArrayList<Integer>`

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ʒˆ¯¤¢@
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//1KTTbYfWH1pyaJHD///RhjpGOsZQbKID4hnGchkBAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##TVU7jlRBDMw5xWjiTvpju5tkCUiIiJBWGj2JRRCQLEi7i0RAygE4AiInQRxgQjjU4C7X60WrNzPP7S67yp/9cHfz5v27y6fji9uPD/dPD8f0@fWr51fHw83t28Px6jo9Ob58uOfR5c@3v1/PP88/zt@v755dvqTz76vzr8vpdMqppMqnpfmWt1S2dDidzI01jW1a/HWemv@18AmjpuEm9WdMz0KjzIvuOfxomVvq8K4AEj/WHUYA0XEwg2pq@9FMbR64yb@LP/URMLuxIfPmgObvdb@X3SB@JHDKCDAzHY4QgebnzGX@9nAV1@ah@rWBgAZFBqAUdgGJjEQaPMqE@P96A8u4ON9nFgWXpngTpuMz4xmAEvgrfCKwy9YW5HQymCWF5IV0Ct7ViQioKOCMqoifVf4ZBAzhM7D6Y8GmFh1QhSSNdBsuZwAaAlTwGuClYGiA3bU2yFWBsH@6@jufjFyVGnbq2Khs6C4ouoFpX1LFSfRWRWoFVuVvjVoklH7nNgDaACCENjLorEtFzYJ1Z1UG2FT8FrSlIDmFQo2KRCfviAX@3tWDoaMuAqbRUwa4yjwrJG/8LgAwMpTFJq@gQcIYMHAKdImhGtBN4BsxFd6Dpy1aXTjfGS4FXAaYC/hGBfcpUUAOrAhjugOJFCTT2QmK8xieCuK7LhYdQAJ7qaPfgmBnygO1gFTb7E@kWbg4or10XezURalRB3QBDVm9Mu2V2gyOp3KCBsJ2pFtAMiLEqhGSz/QYsGeOdiZNb@ycmakhdsyncjvJqs4uqrKDo8qxTRoqV9jNhZOqrHYBE1nNaSxC55Qb5qgwV@P4Vvjbav@YOeEqxCqNFl4MKho7c6OGVpl7X9dmjAJFRYJxjHnkltl/Y41cRrTG3syLdWy06OG8Jj7WiK79FYs86lqBVBi3c1rG/o/Ktu0f).

**Explanation:**

```python
ʒ       # Filter the (implicit) input-list by:
 ˆ      #  Pop and push the current value to the global array
  ¯     #  Push the global array
   ¤    #  Get its last item (without popping the list itself)
    ¢   #  Count how many times it occurs in the global array
     @  #  And check if the (implicit) input-integer is >= this count
        # (after which the filtered list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 46 bytes

```factor
[ '[ [ dup inc get _ > ] reject ] with-scope ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVK9TsMwEJYY-xTHxJRKsRMngJQVsbBUTFGFIuO0BfJD7AhVUZ-EJQusPA88DedL1ThBIqfzz9333Z_z_pln0lRN_3O2ul_d3t1cwbNqSvUCmdaV1JA3eygyswWtXltVSqWhbpQx-7rZlQbKrFC6zqz5etEtAL8OJQKOcgkH8FHPwUuORjSdQAE6I5QAGMEc6OBiDlggNcI1wt3GZSPYdbmEkPIFqOIvxXW6JcUUjFP-EO9iXtgICCfUkCqIiWibF4idUEcAt64TkeHdWgUFZ6h8WuwcwGczDGiCdg0xgU_02SwZuVyiLT8ku08IQU9hBxUfmxgq9elsW-FjyP_JEbVgWzx8tCb34u9lChcppPDY1rArJWyUgQdIYA2NelLS4OFtZ7aellWtYD2wvjpMSH9hUmQ1LAdr3w_7Lw)

- `'[ ... _ ]` A fried quotation. Slot the top value on the data stack (\$n\$) into the `_`.
- `[ ... ] with-scope` Variables set in this quotation get cleared afterward. Without this, the function is not idempotent.
- `[ ... ] reject` Remove values from a sequence for which `[ ... ]` returns true.
- `dup inc get` Increment the value at the current sequence element. In other words, uses the current element as a variable (key) to store and increment its count.
- `>` Is it greater than \$n\$?

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 57 bytes

```
f(l,n)=l[[l[1...i][l=l[i]].lengthfori=[1...l.length]]<=n]
```

The double `.length` is really bugging me but I can't think of a way to circumvent that at the moment...

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zymyfcrrw9)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wisdlt4shq)